# Nested block comments?

Tags: comments

Is there any way to get nestable block comments in LaTeX?  I am using the `comment` package to get block comments, but nesting one comment inside another with `\begin{comment}...\begin{comment}...\end{comment}...\end{comment}` doesn't seem to work.  (I get an error "\begin{document} ended by \end{comment}".)

When writing and revising papers, it would be useful to me to be able to comment out arbitrary blocks of text, even if they already have commented-out blocks within them.

I'm aware that there are editor-based solutions.  What I'm asking is if there is a way to do this within the source of my LaTeX document.

Comment: I usually simply use CTRL+T in Texmaker and you can do nested comments with that.

Comment: Go to Edit menu. I'm almost sure that your editor has the capability of insert comments on the selected block of text.

Comment: I'm aware that there are editor-based solutions (although I don't use Texmaker).  What I'm asking is whether there is a way to do this from within the document source.

Comment: What does a nested comment mean?  Isn't the inner text already a comment?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes.  I edited my question to clarify.  The point is that if I have `Blah \begin{comment}blah blah\end{comment} more blah`, I want to be able to wrap the entire thing in another comment, without worrying about whether it already has a comment inside it.

Comment: By comment, do you just mean "to go away from the input" or "to go away from the output"?  Also, must it rely on the comment package, or are other solutions viable?

Comment: `comment` is similar to `verbatim`: it ends as soon as the string `\end{comment}` is scanned. You can't nest `comment` environments.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Just to go away from the output.  It doesn't need to depend on the comment package, although I would prefer a drop-in solution (i.e., another package) rather than a bit of code that I have to copy and paste around myself.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I figured that out.  The question is, what can I do instead of that to get nested comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest a wrapper command, that uses the block which should be commented as an argument and 'drops it into the trash bin'.

`\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{%
}%`

```
\mycomment{%

Other stuff...
}%
```

This works as long as the commented block follows correct `LaTeX` syntax, i.e. no unclosed right `}` or something similar, however, in such cases, compilation will fail eventually without the comment anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.  I wrapped it in an environment because I like to see the `\end{mycomment}` at the end of a long commented-out block so it reminds me that what is ending is a comment and not some other command.

Comment: Using an environment as you stated was once also my way of doing comments,  but it was tedious to write the end statement, so I switched to the command version.

Comment: +1 as nesting `\comment{ \comment{ }}` now works like a charm.  I now stopped using `\usepackage{comment}` because it does not nest properly!

Answer (score 0):

I use `\ifx` ended by `\fi`. It searches for a token, that's what I don't want, therefore I use `\ifx\relax`. A tiny example illustrates it, it typesets `a e`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
a
\ifx\relax
b
\ifx\relax
c
\fi
d
\fi
e
\end{document}
```