# Recursive or nested comment blocks

Tags: comments, nesting

I know we can comment out a block of text in Latex using `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` commands. However, when I call this recursively (or in a nested fashion) as shown below, it fails:

```
\begin{comment} % block 1
some text
\begin{comment} % block 2
some text
\end{comment} % block 2
some text
\end{comment} % block 1
```

The above code should comment entire text but gives error. I need the above code for example, when I decide later to remove block 1 comment, but still want to keep block 2 commented.

This is just a simple example. We can as well have another block 3 within block 1 and then decide to keep block 3 commented but remove blocks 1 and 2.

Comment: You could simply make `comment` not see the `\end{comment}` of block 2 by changing it to something different of `\end{comment}` (`\ end{comment}`, for example). In fact, adding a comment at the end of the line, like in your example, is enough to make the `\end{comment}` unseen. I think this is much easier than trying to balance the `\begin`s and `\end`s. In fact, balancing verbatim environments (such as `comment`) is usually a problem...

Comment: Thank you @PhelypeOleinik, this information is also very useful!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have just now tried your solution. Adding a comment at the end of `\end{comment}` does not seem to work. Also, changing to `\ end{comment}` gives error as there is no corresponding `\end{comment}` for `\begin{comment}`

Comment: The `comment` package (for any other package this may not apply) checks for a line containing _exactly_ `\end{comment}`. Anything else will not be "seen" and will be considered part of the comment. Taking the example from your question: if you compile it, it will throw an error, will it not? Because neither `\end{comment}` is seen because of the comments at the end of the lines. If you remove the `% block 1` comment from the `\end`, everything will be considered as a comment. Also, changing the block 2 `\end` to `\ end` will hide it and only the second `\end` will be seen. It should work...

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166920/7832 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428082/7832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple version of a `comment` environment that supports nesting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcount\comment@nesting

\newenvironment{comment}{%
    \begingroup
    \global\comment@nesting=0
    \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12\relax}%
    \dospecials
    \catcode`\^^M=\active
    \comment@processline
}{%
    \endgroup
}

\begingroup
\escapechar=-1
\xdef\comment@begincomment{\string\\begin\string\{comment\string\}}
\xdef\comment@endcomment{\string\\end\string\{comment\string\}}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active
\def\@temp{\endgroup\def\comment@processline##1^^M}%
\@temp{%
    \def\comment@curline{#1}%
    \let\@next=\comment@processline
    \ifx\comment@curline\comment@endcomment
        \ifnum\comment@nesting=0
            \def\@next{\end{comment}}%
        \else
            \global\advance\comment@nesting by -1
        \fi
    \else
        \ifx\comment@curline\comment@begincomment
            \global\advance\comment@nesting by 1
        \fi
    \fi
    \@next
}

\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

Some
\begin{comment}
simple comment
\end{comment}
text.

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\begin{comment}
\item Commented out
\end{comment}
\item Third
\end{enumerate}

More
\begin{comment}
simple comment
\begin{comment}
nested comment
\begin{comment}
even deeper nested comment
\end{comment}
\begin{comment}
another deeply nested comment
\end{comment}
some odd characters: _^$%&#
unbalanced braces: }}}}{{{
ignored end of comment:
  \end{comment}
\end{comment}
simple comment again
\end{comment}
text.
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

`\begin{comment}` starts a verbatim environment that processes the following code line by line. Each line contents is tested against the sequences `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` to keep track of nesting in a global counter. All other lines are ignored completely.

Comment: Thank you @siracusa, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: May I suggest that you log a bugfix suggestion so that \usepackage{comment} can be updated.